# Supposed one could give you Cockayne, would you strife for Nibbana?

Tags: right-view

Thought there is a great Guru, displaying personally the joy of abundance and teaches the attaining of [Cockaigne](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockaigne), would you still seek for Nibbana?

**Yes? No? If, or if not, why?**

*He doubts you have any argument against it, you just don't know the way!*

`"Don't get it wrong!"`[He](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/index-names_en.html#mara)`says:`

`"`[There](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradise)`is endless sense pleasure,
 for all strings,
    no aging, no sickness,
         no death.`

`Eating the whole day
         without belly pain...
Cockaigne is not temporary.`

`Your favorit food, pleasure
as long as you like,
chaning it as you wish.`

`By abundance
Detached from any stressful'
    no consequence,
non-dual 
        in that sphere!"
who seek rel-ease
        from IS`

Answer (score 1):

What are you talking about? Nibbana *is* Cockaigne.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67808/discussion-on-answer-by-andrei-volkov-supposed-one-could-give-you-cockayne-woul).

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer from my perspective, but the answer is a straightforwards yes; I would still strive for nirvana given I had come in contact with Buddhist teachings. There are many reasons for this:

- Karmically speaking, what occurs within that temporary land is irrelevant. What truly matters is what will happen to me in the vaster perspective. I think of this as a temporary versus long-term benefit type of thing.
- From a perspective of wisdom, I would still be suffering by engaging in those pleasures, they would merely hide or distract me from true happiness. Such a happiness might entail equanimity arising from perceiving reality.
- From a compassionate point of view, there are people suffering, and with such a selfish attitude I would not be able to develop myself in a way conducive to helping others. It would be a completely narcissistic choice.

I think in my answer I expressed the three dimensions involved in the Mahayana Buddhist path: [aspiring to liberation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refuge_(Buddhism)), [bodhicitta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhicitta), and [the insight into emptiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9A%C5%ABnyat%C4%81).

I think, in fact, that we even *conceive* we'd be happier shows us the nature of delusion. We can imagine we'd be happy with intense pleasures, but the reality is otherwise, showing the discrepancy between our perception and reality. Nothing *within this world* shows us this discrepancy, and the proof is that many people *do* live in this way, seeking pleasures. Only the transcendent understanding from insight provides immunity from this misapprehension, and dealing with reality in a worldly way -- as in with your example of Cockaigne -- will hinder such insight.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67783/discussion-on-answer-by-eggman-supposed-one-could-give-you-cockayne-would-you-s).

Answer (score 0):

Nibbana is not cockaigne, because its said that there is no want in Nibbana and that is bliss!

Even here in Samsara wealth consists not in having great possessions, but in having few wants, So if you are aiming to have fewer want you are following the true path.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67782/discussion-on-answer-by-epic-supposed-one-could-give-you-cockayne-would-you-str).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about five strength of a being ; Conviction (saddhā),Energy (viriya), Mindfulness (sati), Unification (samādhi), Wisdom (paññā) which impossible for none other than Buddha to see.  If one poses these five strength enough, he would seek deathlessness. Five strengths is what makes one strive for Nirvana, however we need to see if the environment he is in, such as Cockaigne, affects any of those 5????

i can think of reading sutta of what can be credited to Buddha's words about Uttarakuru country. It is the closest to Cockaigne I can think of.  None of them make any progress in Dharma. Buddha compared Uttarakuru country to us and tavatimsa deva in that world; 1)  No pain, 2) no jealousy, 3) fixed life expectancy.   And yet, no one in that world strives to make progress toward Nirvana.

In general, if you want to know drives or motivation and ability to strive in Nirvana, you need to look at being's five strength.

IMO, causal of Five Strengths in a being is both from Nature and Nurtured.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67790/discussion-on-answer-by-dean-a-supposed-one-could-give-you-cockayne-would-you).